ES6 import - express is not a function
Error while running the localhost server and it is saying express is not a function.


First I created a folder to install package.json in it.
mkdir '3.2 HTTP Requests'

cd 'C:\Users\Aditi baghel\programs\.vscode\Web Development Projects\Udemy Web course\New_backend\3.2 HTTP Requests'

npm init


Then when package.json is made, I edited
'type' = 'module' 

in it.
content inside package.json
{
  "name": "3.2-http-requests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.7.0",
    "cookie": "^0.7.1",
    "express": "^2.5.11",
    "mime": "^4.0.4",
    "qs": "^6.13.0"
  }
}


then I created a new file index.js.

In the terminal I wrote
npm i express


Then I wrote the code inside index.js.

I run it by writingnode index.js in the terminal.
My version of node.js is 18.20.0  when I attached the error express is not a function at the very end of it.
It is mentioning the version of my node.js.


I tried to run server on my localhost and I was expecting it would work properly but it didn't.
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is on port ${port}`);
})


If you're starting a new project why are you using such an old version of Express?

It was my mistake. By mistake I installed it.

Your Express version is v2, and all the internet resources are written for v4.
So, you need to check the v2 documentation at https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/2.5.11
The syntax for express v2 is:
import express from 'express';

const app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);

Note that to debug this issue, it is possible to simply log what express is:
import express from 'express';
console.log(express);

This would point you in the right direction.

Thank you, I have got the same suggestion from someone. I have not known how the old version got installed and noticed that after someone has pointed out. It was a very silly move.
